# DateTime format serialization with unspecified DateTimeKind

Tags: c#, json.net

I have written a small example shown a deserialization of datetime type from string using Json.NET library:

1. With specified offset
2. Not specified time zone
3. With UTC time zone(with Z)

   ```
   JsonSerializerSettings settings = new JsonSerializerSettings();
   settings.DateTimeZoneHandling = DateTimeZoneHandling.Utc;
   settings.DateFormatHandling = DateFormatHandling.IsoDateFormat;
   // With offset
   string d1 = "\"2018-03-14T06:29:29+05:00\"";
   DateTime date1 = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<DateTime>(d1, settings);
   Console.WriteLine("date1: " + date1.ToString("o"));
   // Not specified
   string d2 = "\"2018-03-14T06:29:29\"";
   DateTime date2 = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<DateTime>(d2, settings);
   Console.WriteLine("date2: " + date2.ToString("o"));
   // With Z
   string d3 = "\"2018-03-14T06:29:29Z\"";
   DateTime date3 = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<DateTime>(d3, settings);
   Console.WriteLine("date3: " + date3.ToString("o"));

   Console.ReadLine();
   ```

I set up [`DateTimeZoneHandling`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/SerializeDateTimeZoneHandling.htm) to handle a time zone as UTC. 
My local time zone has an offset `+03:00`.

According [ISO8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601#Time_zone_designators),

> Time zones in ISO 8601 are represented as local time (with the
>   location unspecified), as UTC, or as an offset from UTC.

I am expecting to see the output as below

date1: 2018-03-14T01:29:29.0000000Z
**date2: 2018-03-14T03:29:29.0000000Z**
date3: 2018-03-14T06:29:29.0000000Z

But I get a such output

date1: 2018-03-14T01:29:29.0000000Z
**date2: 2018-03-14T06:29:29.0000000Z**
date3: 2018-03-14T06:29:29.0000000Z

The deserilization from strings with Z and with not specified time zone produce the same value.

I don't undestand such behaviour. 
**Question: Is the such behaviour not contrary to the ISO 8601?**

***UPDATE:***

I added a datetime offset to output in my example and it seem like even more strang for me.

```
    JsonSerializerSettings settings = new JsonSerializerSettings();
    settings.DateTimeZoneHandling = DateTimeZoneHandling.Utc;
    settings.DateFormatHandling = DateFormatHandling.IsoDateFormat;
    string d1 = "\"2018-03-14T06:29:29+05:00\"";
    DateTime date1 = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<DateTime>(d1, settings);
    DateTimeOffset date1Offset = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<DateTimeOffset>(d1, settings);
    Console.WriteLine("date1: " + date1.ToString("o"));
    Console.WriteLine("date1Offset: " + date1Offset.ToString("o"));

    string d2 = "\"2018-03-14T06:29:29\"";
    DateTime date2 = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<DateTime>(d2, settings);
    DateTimeOffset date2Offset = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<DateTimeOffset>(d2, settings);
    Console.WriteLine("date2: " + date2.ToString("o"));
    Console.WriteLine("date2Offset: " + date2Offset.ToString("o"));

    string d3 = "\"2018-03-14T06:29:29Z\"";
    DateTime date3 = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<DateTime>(d3, settings);
    DateTimeOffset date3Offset = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<DateTimeOffset>(d3, settings);
    Console.WriteLine("date3: " + date3.ToString("o"));
    Console.WriteLine("date3Offset: " + date3Offset.ToString("o"));
```

**Updated output:**

date1: 2018-03-14T01:29:29.0000000Z
date1Offset: 2018-03-14T06:29:29.0000000+05:00

date2: 2018-03-14T06:29:29.0000000Z
date2Offset: 2018-03-14T06:29:29.0000000+03:00

date3: 2018-03-14T06:29:29.0000000Z
date3Offset: 2018-03-14T06:29:29.0000000+00:00

Comment: `var date2 = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<DateTimeOffset>(d2, settings); Console.WriteLine(date2.ToUniversalTime());`

Comment: @Jimi, I have added. Thank you for the tip

Comment: The second case, deserializing to a DateTimeOffset (as it should be), if you now print `date2Offset.ToUniversalTime()` you should get `3/14/2018 3:29:29 AM +00:00`. Which is what you're expecting.

Comment: @Jimi, Sure, I get it for datetimeoffset type, but not for datetime. I explicity set up `settings.DateTimeZoneHandling = DateTimeZoneHandling.Utc;`  I expect to see automatic converting datetime to utc. What is connection beetween datetime and datetimeoffset types?

Comment: That's why you deserialize to DateTimeOffset. DateTime doesn't have TimeZone informations. It's converted using the initial settings and that's all you get back. In the first case, the offset is applied to the conversion, in the second example there's no offset. DateTimeOffset has both `UTCDateTime` and `LocalDateTime`. That's why you prefer DateTimeOffset.

Comment: Why do DateTimeOffset get the offset using initial setting but the DateTime not get offset? I think the DateTime and DateTimeOffset closly related if these was got from one string. According ISO8601 I get al local time but not UTC in the second case unlike other cases.

Comment: Look at the second string: `2018-03-14T06:29:29`. Now, say, without any doubts, if this is a local or an UTC date. Did you ask for an UTC date? Well, then lets assume it's an UTC date. DateTimeOffset can record both. DateTime cannot, so you have to choose. You see this kind of mishap all the time. JSON dates are not represented as .Net DateTime objects. They're represented, correctly, as a complex information. The closer .Net format is DateTimeOffset. Also, those settings have a diffferent meaning when you Serialize and when you Deserialize.

Comment: @Jimi, thank you for discuss. I got what I wanted to know